# with my/me being a

Tags: personal-pronouns, case

> Worst of all is Waking‘s overreliance on colors for its map interface. I’m trying my best here being told to go to the exit via the magenta dots on the map. Or if I have to complete a nearby objective, it’s shown by a green dot on the map. But **with my being a colorblind player**, differentiating between the often criminally close colors on that minimap is extremely frustrating. (from [PCINVASION](https://www.pcinvasion.com/waking-review/))

> **The Dangers of Birthing as a Black Woman**
>
> From almost the moment I found out I was pregnant, I worried. Every mom-to-be worries—Will I have pregnancy complications? Will my child be healthy? Will I poop during labor?—but **with my being a black woman in America**, the realization quickly set in: Being pregnant meant putting my well-being, even my life, on the line in a way that white moms, statistically, don’t have to. (from [GLAMOUR](https://www.glamour.com/story/i-chose-an-unassisted-home-birth))

Is the use of **my** in these articles correct? Or should it be **me** instead?

### EDIT

Both @Dialfrost and @Ringo claim that **my** as well as **me** is correct in the above examples, and @Ringo even goes as far as to suggest:

> a student learning English should use "my being," because in a test of formal/written English, "my being" is going to be considered the correct syntax.

But please note that I'm not asking about any construction containing "my being", but specifically about the construction "with my being a..." being used as a supplement of a sentence (as opposed to a complement of a sentence).

For example, [the link provided by @Dialfrost](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/31437/27275) asks about this sentence:

> *They always hated my/me being an atheist.*

Where *my/me being an atheist* is a complement of the sentence. And here, I don't object to using *my*. This is also verified by [Ngram #1 (hated me being a,hated my being a)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hated%20me%20being%20a%2Chated%20my%20being%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chated%20me%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chated%20my%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chated%20me%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chated%20my%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0).

But [Ngram #2 (but with my being a,but with me being a,but with his being a,but with him being a)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+with+my+being+a%2Cbut+with+me+being+a%2Cbut+with+his+being+a%2Cbut+with+him+being+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbut%20with%20me%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbut%20with%20him%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0) tells us that the *my*/*his* versions are non-existent. Note that *with my/me/his/him being a* in this Ngram has to be a supplement of a sentence because the *with*-phrase comes right after *but*.

In contrast, [Ngram #3 (do with my being a,do with me being a,do with his being a,do with him being a)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20with%20my%20being%20a%2Cdo%20with%20me%20being%20a%2Cdo%20with%20his%20being%20a%2Cdo%20with%20him%20being%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20with%20my%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20with%20me%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20with%20his%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20with%20him%20being%20a%3B%2Cc0) says that both *my*/*his* and *me*/*him* versions are attested.

Comment: If I'm correct, adding a "with" in front does not make a difference

Comment: In Ngram #2, you should exclude the "but" -- there's no good reason for that to be in the phrase you're searching

Comment: I've amended my answer to point out that these phrases are "objects of a preposition."

Comment: @Ringo No, there _is_ a reason for including _but_ in Ngram #2. It's because if I didn't include _but_ or _and_, the search results would include phrases like Ngram #3 where _with my/me/his/him being a..._ is not a supplement of the sentence.

Comment: Remind me not to answer your questions anymore

Comment: @Ringo You're gonna run away like that?

Comment: I guess you can call it that. I'm pretty sure I don't have the right answer for you. I'm not an English grammar expert. I did give it my best shot, but I don't want to get more negative votes. IMO, this is better suited for the English stack, not the learners'. There are more people there who enjoy answering questions like this one.

Comment: @Ringo But thanks for answering anyway. I will post the question on the ELU if I don't get any more answers. If there's anything I learned on ELL and ELU, it's that I shouldn't give a shit about the votes.